# HTTPS Authentication problem : Polipo

Tags: networking, proxy, authentication, http-proxy, htaccess

I use internet behind http proxy, and that requires authentication. I tried using polipo to bypass the authenticated proxy to 127.0.0.1:9134.

Applying these settings to my browser, works fine for http://examplewebsite.com

but for https://examplewebsite.com, it asks for authentication. Also my host proxy authentication does not work in the authentication dialog.

Settings I have changed in my `/etc/polipo/config`

```
proxyPort=9134

parentProxy = "172.31.1.10:8080"

parentAuthCredentials = "username:mypassword"
```